# Why are my sampled values are non Gaussian?

Tags: monte-carlo, central-limit-theorem, numerical-integration

I just have a quick question regarding Importance Sampling Monte Carlo integration. If I sample from some pdf, $p(x,y)$, to calculate an integral. I.e., $I = \int f(x,y) \ dx\ dy$

It can be approximated by,

$I \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}^{N} \frac{f(x_{i},y_{i})}{p(x_{i},y_{i})}$ if $x \sim p_{x}(x)$ and $y \sim p_{y}(y)$.

According to the Central Limit Theorem, as the number of samples increases towards infinity, the sampled values should tend towards a normal distribution. Whereby "sampled values" I mean the values of $\frac{f(x_{i},y_{i})}{p(x_{i},y_{i})}$

However, in my case, the samples don't. The distribution that appears is similar to a Gaussian except it has an extremely long tail on one side which biases the mean value of the distribution, even though the mode of the distribution aligns with the exact value.

Could be due to finite sampling affects, a poor pdf used for sampling, or have I misunderstood the Central Limit Theorem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know how you apply CLT here. CLT states that the distribution of the sum of random variables approaches to Gaussian.

Comment: @Xi'an The pair $(x_i, y_i)$ is simulated from the two marginal distributions $p_x(x_i)$ and $p_y(y_i)$.

Comment: @kevin012 I haven't applied it to anything, it's just I thought that the random variables would tend to a Gaussian distribution as the number of samples tends to infinity. And, my samples don't, they tend towards a Gaussian-like distribution with an extremely long tail only on one side which distorts the mean value.

Comment: I do not understand: if you simulate from the marginals but use the joint in the importance ration, it cannot work. Unless the joint happens to be the product of the marginals (independence).

Comment: @Xi'an I am assuming that the joint distribution is the product of the marginals. As the method, I use for sampling is the Inverse Transform Sampling method and that can only work on 1D pdfs.

Comment: @Xi'an Although, now that you mention it, the joint-probability might be the problem. My function is roughly defined as $f(x,y) = x^2 f_x(x) y^2 f_y(y) V(x,y)$ and I sample in accordance to $x \sim p_x(x) = x^2 f_x(x)$ and likewise for $y$. However, the $V(x,y)$ term does have terms in it which are dependent on both $x$ and $y$ which would break this assumption that the joint probability can be based on the product of the marginal probabilities, and I would need to include some projection of $V(x,y)$  along the $x$ and $y$ axis to correct for that!

Comment: @Xi'an the variance of the importance ratio is finite!

Comment: Definitely a problem. You need to simulate from $p_X$ and from $p_{Y|X}$ then.

Comment: So, I would need to re-define $p_x(x)$ to equal $x^2 f_x(x) V_x(x)$ and sample proportional to that, and for $y$ sample $p_y(y) = \frac{p(x,y)}{p_x(x)} $!?

Comment: Also, a late question following up on this. If I sample from the marginal and increase the number of samples wouldn't it just reduce the error to the exact result? Or does this interdependence between x and y bias this type of sampling?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether I understand this 100%, but I can well imagine that this happens due to a bad choice of the pdf $p$. The ratio can get very large in places in which $p(x_i,y_i)$ is very small and $f(x_i,y_i)$ is not. The CLT requires variances to exist, and such ratios can have variances that either don't exist or behave very nastily so that extremely large $n$ is required for the normal approximation to work.

By the way I'm assuming that by "the sampled values should tend towards a normal distribution" you mean the simulated values of $I$ rather than the sampled $x$ and $y$ themselves.

Comment: (+1) Indeed the CLT only applies when the variance of $f(X,Y)/p(X,Y)$ is finite and importance sampling is not automatically protected from having infinite variance.

Comment: @Lewian yes, that's what I mean by "the sampled values should tend towards a normal distribution". I'll make the appropriate changes to the question!